# Doctrine2 : condition on conditions

Tags: search, doctrine-orm, conditional-statements, addition, where-clause

What I'd like to do seems pretty "classic", but I don't find any example...
It's for a kind of search form, with mostly optionnal parameters.

Here is my code :

```
$obj = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("p")
            ->from("Client")
        if ($email) {
            $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.email', ':email'));
        }
        if ($name) {
            $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.name', ':name'));
        }
        if ($firstname) {
            $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.firstname', ':firstname'));
        }
        if ($postalCode) {
            $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.postalCode', ':postalCode'));
        }

$obj->setParameters(array('email' => $email,'name'=> $name, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'postalCode' => $postalCode))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But, of course, if I have some parameters at `null` : `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

I'm sure there is a better way to achieve that, I just don't find it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an array variable called $parameters, Then within the body of each if statement, set  it

```
$parameters = array()
$obj = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("p")
    ->from("Client")...

if ($email) {
    $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.email', ':email'));
    $parameters['email'] = $email;
}
if ($name) {
    $obj->add('where', $obj->expr()->like('p.name', ':name'));
    $parameters['name'] = $name;
}
...

$obj->setParameters($parameters)->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Great, don't know why I didn't think about it. Thanks !